# Не устанавливается User-Agent

Tags: golang

Хочу установить `User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10_5_8) AppleWebKit/536.17+ (KHTML, like Gecko) iCab/5.0 Safari/533.16`. Когда устанавливаю и вывожу `req.Header` то пишет что он присутствует, но когда я отслеживаю запрос Wiresharkом то там совсем другой user agent, а именно `Go-http-client` то есть получается так что агент не был установлен. Может это я что-то путаю или так оно и есть?

Код:

```
req, err := http.Get(host)
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10_5_8) AppleWebKit/536.17+ (KHTML, like Gecko) iCab/5.0 Safari/533.16")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(req.Header)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заголовок надо устанавливать до выполнения запроса. Примерно вот так:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com", nil)
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10_5_8) AppleWebKit/536.17+ (KHTML, like Gecko) iCab/5.0 Safari/533.16")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```